# Realizar una copia de archivos que están dentro de un txt en powershell

Tags: script, powershell

Estoy pegado para terminar un script ya que no logro hacer para que de un archivo txt que tengo varias rutas hacer que por medio de script lea esas rutas que siempre van a ser cambiantes las tome y busque el archivo que indica cada ruta

Algo asi como esto:

Este archivo contiene una serie de rutas:

```
$computers = gc "C:\scripts\servers.txt"
```

Necesito que el script lea cada ruta y vaya buscar un archivo especifico:

```
$source = "C:\scripts\servers.txt"
```

Y que cada archivo sea colocado en otra ruta especifica:

```
$destination = "C$\temp\"
```

Asi tal vez, con algo como esto, puedo mover esos archivos al destino:

```
foreach ($computer in $computers) {Copy-Item $source -Destination "\\$computer\$destination" -Recurse}
```

Comment: No queda muy claro el problema; necesitas que se lea de un txt rutas o nombres de equipos? Esos nombres condicionan la variable $source?

Comment: ok vamos a ver si me puedo explicar mejor 
si aplico el get-content a un archivo txt puedo ver las rutas donde estan los archivos que necesito
Get-Content .\copy.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Training zone Cycling.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\como bajar videos de facebook.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\promerica.txt

Ahora lo que necesito es que por medio de algun script 

pueda ir a cada una de esas rutas y traer los archivos .txt y colocarlos en otro folder or ruta
algo asi como moverlos a 
C:\Users\user\Documents\

Answer (score 0):

Si mal no entendí, tu situación es la siguiente:

Tienes un archivo con rutas de archivos llamado **archivos.txt** en *C:\scripts\archivos.txt*, con la siguiente información (ejemplo):

```
C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Desktop\Archivo1.txt
C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Desktop\Archivo2.txt
...
C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Desktop\ArchivoN.txt
```

Y necesitas guardar los archivos que aparecen definidos en el archivo anterior en la siguiente carpeta, por ejemplo:

```
C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Documents
```

El script sería el siguiente:

```
$archivos = Get-Content 'C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Desktop\archivos.txt'
$destino = 'C:\Users\vmsilvamolina\Documents'
foreach ($archivo in $archivos) {
    Copy-Item -Path $archivo -Destination $destino
}
```

Comment: ok dejame intentarlo y te estare confirmando

Answer (score 0):

Estimado

Disculpa si soy un poco lento para entender o estoy omitiendo algo basado en la ayuda que me enviaste intente crear el script y ajustarlo a mis necesidades pero me esta mostrando un error 
he revisado la escritura de arriba a abajo pero no logro detectar el problema

mira como lo hice

```
Get-Content 'C:\Users\miusuario\Documents\copy.txt'
pause
$archivos = Get-Content 'C:\Users\miusuario\Documents\copy.txt'

$destino = 'C:\Users\miusuario\Pictures'

foreach ($archivo in $archivos ) {
Copy-Item -Path $archivo -Destination $destino
}
```

Pero mira el resultado

```
PS C:\Users\miusuario> Get-Content 'C:\Users\miusuario\Documents\copy.txt'
pause
$archivos = Get-Content 'C:\Users\miusuario\Documents\copy.txt'

$destino = 'C:\Users\miusuario\Pictures'

foreach ($archivo in $archivos ) {
Copy-Item -Path $archivo -Destination $destino
}
C:\Users\miusuario\Desktop\Training zone Cycling.txt
C:\Users\miusuario\Desktop\como bajar videos de facebook.txt
C:\Users\miusuario\Desktop\promerica.txt

Press Enter to continue...: 
Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At line:8 char:17
+ Copy-Item -Path $archivo -Destination $destino
+                 ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Comment: y cual es el contenido del archivo copy.txt?

Answer (score 0):

mira cambie esta linea y si funciono

```
foreach ($archivo in $archivos ) {
Copy-Item 'C:\Users\miusuario\Documents\copy.txt' -Destination $destino
}  

Los archivos que contenian ese txt se movieron a la ruta 

$destino = 'C:\Users\miusuario\Pictures'
```

Ahora si viene lo real

mira esto

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit}
#Variable utilizada = 
$Fullpath = $env:ANALYSIS_PATH + "\orchidtmp\Result"
#Aqui simplemente muestro todo el path completo
Write-Host $Fullpath

#Aqui el usuario ingresa un valor que siempre sera variable
$Request1 = Read-Host -Prompt "RUNID"

#Aqui el sistema va a revisar la ruta
$checkpath = Test-Path $Fullpath

# si la ruta es valida 
if($checkpath -eq $true) {
# Aqui se muestra un mensaje que el archivo existe
Write-Host "the file exist"

#aqui se muestra si contiene el archivo que buscamos 
Get-ChildItem $Fullpath\*_$Request1\Run_$Request1\res$Request1\TEST1.txt 

pause
cls

}

#Aqui se haran unos remplazos de caracteres especiales dentro del documento hice dos lineas para tenerlas un poco mas identificadas
Get-ChildItem $Fullpath\*_$Request1\Run_$Request1\res$Request1\TEST1.txt | ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_ -Raw).Replace("%",":") | Set-Content $_}  
Get-ChildItem $Fullpath\*_$Request1\Run_$Request1\res$Request1\TEST1.txt | ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_ -Raw).Replace("#","\") | Set-Content $_}  

Pause 

#Aqui mostrare el archivo ya con los caracteres remplazados y listo para entrar a la ultima parte
Get-Content $Fullpath\*_$Request1\Run_$Request1\res$Request1\"TEST1.txt"  

#Basado en la ayuda que me enviaste esta es la ruta donde esta el archivo con las diferentes rutas contenidas 
$archivos = Get-Content $Fullpath\*_$Request1\Run_$Request1\res$Request1\"TEST1.txt" 

#Este es el Destino de cada archivo que necesito mandar a traer 
$destino =  "$Fullpath\*_$Request1\Run_$Request1\res$Request1\"

pause 
#Y aqui he hecho todos los cambios posibles pero no logra mover los archivos a destino
foreach ($archivo in $archivos) {
Copy-Item -Path $archivo -Destination $destino

}
pause
```

Este es el error que muestra

Copy-Item : Illegal characters in path.
At C:\Users\miusuario\Google
Drive\Programacion\Scripting-PowerShell\Powershell-Scripts\First_Step_Search_Env_File1.2.ps1:58 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Path $archivo -Destination $destino
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand